# Changing the location of a Label

Tags: c#

I have tried to programmatically set the location of a label but the compiler says it is not a variable,

```
label1.Location.X = 200;// shows an error
```

is there any trick I could use to move labels around which does not include hiding and showing controls.

The technology is visual c# not WPF.

I'm looking for a way to move some text on the form,I separated the characters of the text, label for each, and also the mathematic formula

```
(x',y')=center;x'=200,y'=200,r=100
(x,y)=point on the circle.
sqr(x-x')+sqr(y-y')=sqr(r) => sqr(x-200)+sqr(y-200)=10000 => sqr(x)-400x+sqr(y)-400y+70000=0 =>  
x1=(400+sqrt(160000-4sqr(y)+1600y-280000))/2 ; 
x2=(400-sqrt(160000-4sqr(y)+1600y-280000))/2
```

Also I am thinking of using threads to refresh the form and create the motion, it is just some ideas I am trying to work this out since you are asking.

many thanks.

Comment: We are hungry for code.

Comment: Can you give more detail? This is guesswork otherwise - what technology? Winforms? WPF? MVC? Any code? What's the error? etc.. help us to help you

Comment: thank you for the attention, I have updated the question accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every .NET programmer makes this mistake at least once.  The Location property is a Point, a **value type**.  When you retrieve its value then you get a *copy*, like value types behave.  You are updating the X property of that copy, the compiler can tell that this is *not* what you had in mind.

You have to assign a Point to update the property value:

```
  label1.Location = new Point(200, label1.Location.Y);
```

Or use the property that was made to avoid having to write this code:

```
  label1.Left = 200;
```

Answer (score 2):

To properly change the location of the label, you must set the `Location` to a value (rather than the X property of the `Location`).

```
lbl.Location = new Location(20, 50);
```

If you wish to preserve the Y coordinates, for example, you can do:

```
lbl.Location = new Location(20, lbl.Location.Y);
```

Comment: I may have gotten something wrong, since I'm without VS atm, but I'm sure you can sort it out from there. Glad to help. *edit: totally check out Hans' answer*